# Is there a CSS editor for Aptana or Eclipse that supporting CSSEdit groups?

Tags: css, eclipse, aptana, cssedit

My code is neatly organized in CSSEdit groups, but the others in my team use Aptana or other tools.

Is there a CSS editor for Aptana or Eclipse that supporting CSSEdit groups?

[EDIT] Does Aptana or its editors allow for custom code folding limits? That would be already great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not Aptana, and not any editor for Eclipse I know of, since it's a very CSSEdit-specific feature. It sounds somewhat similar to the region functionality in Visual Studio, though that generally does not show a folder hierarchy.

I would suggest adding a feature request for Aptana at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD